# How can you repair a corrupt ntbackup (.bkf) file?

Tags: windows, backup

I've got a corrupt ntbackup file that won't open in ntbackup.

There are various utilities that a google search turns up that say they can repair the files. Do I need to use one or is there a simple way of using ntbackup to do this?

Comment: I tried NTKbup, but solved the problem using a trial of Symantec Backup exec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: This [forum thread on tek-tips](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=739600&page=1) has some very useful information, like

> Many thanks to Michael (aka mpears)
>   for referring me to the free NTBkup
>   software at
>   http://www.fpns.net/willy/msbackup.htm.
>   Using this software, I was able to
>   recover thousands of files from a
>   corrupted, 20-GB BKF file, saving
>   hundreds of dollars and an untold
>   number of hours in re-creating various
>   documents.

---

As alternative you could try this **commercial software** for [BKF recovery](http://www.recoverybkf.com/).

> Kernel BKF File Repair - Recovers and
>   repairs the files from damaged bkf
>   archives corrupted due to backup
>   interruption, virus attacks, crc
>   errors or backup software corruption.
>   It allows access to corrupt bkf files
>   which can not be restored using the
>   original backup software due to any
>   kind of corruption.

There is also an **open source project** on SourceForge: [JMTF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmtf/)

*Good luck!*

Comment: Currently (July 2015), the BKF / MTF Specification can be found under http://laytongraphics.com/mtf/MTF_100a.PDF and Will Krantzer's pages at http://www.willsworks.net/msbackup.htm and https://sites.google.com/site/willkranz/

Answer (score 0):

If the backed up files within BKF are neither compressed nor encrypted then it is fairly easy - well not too hard - to extract single files manually by using grep, hexedit and dd.

MTF Format: http://laytongraphics.com/mtf/MTF_100a.PDF

Example (assumes using bash shell): extract Outlook.pst

```
grep -a -o -P 'O\x00u\x00t\x00l\x00o\x00o\x00k\x00\.\x00p\x00s\x00t' corrupt.bkf >offsetts.txt
```

Inspect offsets.txt, find offset that is followed by "NACL" "CSUM" and "STAN"

```
OFFSET=123456
dd if=corrupt.bkf bs=512 skip=$(( OFFSET / 512 )) | hexdump -C | less

00000000  46 49 4c 45 00 00 00 00  88 00 0e 02 00 44 bc 55  |FILE.........D.U|
00000010  00 00 00 00 2d 8e 77 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....-.w.........|
00000020  00 00 00 00 88 0a 00 00  00 00 00 00 18 00 70 00  |..............p.|
00000030  02 00 88 9b 00 08 00 00  1f 7a 74 17 73 1f 61 a2  |.........zt.s.a.|
00000040  b2 d7 00 00 00 00 00 1f  7a 74 17 73 54 00 00 00  |........zt.sT...|
00000050  33 0a 00 00 16 00 58 00  4f 00 75 00 74 00 6c 00  |3.....X.O.u.t.l.|
00000060  6f 00 6f 00 6b 00 2e 00  70 00 73 00 74 00 00 00  |o.o.k...p.s.t...|
...
00000170  12 1e 62 a3 33 bf 00 00  53 54 41 4e 00 00 20 00  |..b.3...STAN.. .|
00000180  00 44 bc 55 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 8e 0b 21 42  |.D.U..........!B|
00000190  44 4e c1 7c 3c 6a 53 4d  17 00 13 00 01 01 40 00  |DN.|<jSM......@.|
```

STAN means "Standard stream", the byte count is in 8 bytes (little endian) that begin 4 bytes after "STAN", so in this example `00 44 bc 55 00 00 00 00` or 0x55bc4400 bytes. The file starts at 22 bytes after beginning of STAN, you can see the "!BDN" magic number in the PST Header. To extract the file:

```
OFFSET=$(( OFFSET / 512 * 512 + 0x18e ))
FSIZE=$(( 0x55bc4400 ))
dd if=corrupt.bkf of=Outlook.pst bs=1 skip="$OFFSET" count="$FSIZE"
```

This will take some time if the file is large ... done!